# Paypal IPN, Missing POST Data

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn

I recently have tried to implement Paypal's IPN into my website.
Here are the steps I've taken (sandbox)

1: make a 2 sandbox accounts (buyer/seller)

2: Enable IPN on the seller account and set the URL to my PayPalIPN.php

PayPalIPN.php is https://github.com/paypal/ipn-code-samples/blob/master/php/PaypalIPN.php

3: Create a button, the button goes to success.php after purchase

success.php is https://github.com/paypal/ipn-code-samples/blob/master/php/example_usage.php

Now when I click on buy now, log into my sandbox buyer account, buy it, then press take me back to merchant, I get this error

> Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: Missing POST Data in /home/site/public_html/PayPalIPN.php:60 Stack trace: #0 /home/site/public_html/success.php(7): PaypalIPN->verifyIPN() #1 {main} thrown in /home/site/public_html/PayPalIPN.php on line 60

This is the line that throws the exception

```
 if ( ! count($_POST)) {
       throw new Exception("Missing POST Data");
    }
```

I'm really stumped  on this. I've only seen one question on here with this problem, and Paypal's tutorial doesn't mention what is wrong when this error occurs. I appreciate any help

**UPDATE**

So it seems like I was using some of the URLs in the wrong places. So now I have a IPN class at 'paypalipn.php' and another file called 'success.php' that includes paypalipn.php and uses the IPN class to check if its verified or not. I've set the listener URL to the success.php, and when it is purchased, the user is redirected to 'purchased.php.' The problem I'm having is that it seems like success.php is never called. It simply does not work.. I have also tried setting the URL in the Buy Now button's variables using

```
notify_url=https://www.website.com/success.php
```

It still doesn't seem to get called. I am really confused what I'm doing wrong...

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the .php that was called had an error in it. After I fixed the error, it seemed to get called. Now I'm just trying to figure out how to properly send a custom variable to the IPN.. I keep getting wrong things from $_POST.

Answer (score 0):

Check your url's are correct.

Shouldn't it be like this?

```
 notify_url=https://www.website.com/paypalipn.php

 return_url=https://www.website.com/success.php
```

To check you are receiving the POST variables, you can use the following in success.php to print them on screen.

```
 print_r($_POST);
```

To add custom data, if you are using a form / button, you could do something like this;

```
$custom_data = $myvar;
```

and in the PayPal form add like this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="custom" value="<?php echo $custom_data ;?>">
```

Paypal should return it to your return_url as a posted variable.